# How to animate bottom sheet and its content in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I want to animate a bottom sheet (or a custom made widget) and its content in flutter. The widget should be able to snap to a starting height when items on the screen are pressed. By dragging the bottom sheet or pressing a "read more" button, the bottom sheet should animate its height to show more content. As this animation takes place, widgets with text, images etc should also animate to new positions (**see video**). The content of the bottom sheet should also be able to update if state changes without having to rerender the starting animation.

[image]

I am happy if anyone has any suggestions on where to start and what to do :)

**EDIT**

I watched the video suggested by pskink and found an [article](https://fidev.io/tickets-advanced-transitions/) showing how to build such a design I had in mind. By using an `AnimatedBuilder` and an `AnimationController` I could update the width, height and so on of the widgets, based on how far the animation had animated. See part of the code below:

```dart
   ...

    double get imageWidth => lerp(imageStartWidth,maxWidthInsideSheet);    
    
    double lerp(double min, double max) => lerpDouble(min, max, _controller.value)!;

   ...

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Positioned(
            height: lerp(minHeight, maxHeight),
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragUpdate: _handleDragUpdate,
              onVerticalDragEnd: _handleDragEnd,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  CustomImage(
                    width: imageWidth,
                    ... (more properties), 
                    ...,
                  ),
                  ...,
                  ...
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
    
   ...
```

**This is the result**

[image]

The animation of the widgets inside the custom bottom sheet works perfectly! However, I am not sure how I would animate the custom bottom sheet in the beginning so it doesn't just pop up, but rather slide up as the flutter `ModalButtomSheet` does. The other problem comes when I want to close the bottom sheet by pressing the 'close' button. At the moment, I am calling a function which gets passed from the parent widget which stops rendering this custom bottom sheet. This of course makes the widget disappear. **How would I** implement it, such that the custom bottom sheet can slide up when first rendering and slide down before it stops rendering?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgw819mL_78&t=3s) maybe?

Comment: Do you know how I would implement the animation of the image and the text with this?

Comment: you have `scrollController` passed to `builder` so you can use its `offset` property for building

Comment: more here: https://youtu.be/FCyoHclCqc8?t=1612

Comment: Thanks! I will try and implement it with the help of the video.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: I implemented the design with the help of the video and updated my question. I still have the problem of how to animate the custom bottom sheet in and out (see question).

Comment: Thanks a lot ..... I will try to use and will make update soon....!!!